Looking for GUI Testing Tool for Qt 5.12.12 C++ Widgets Application with VTK 8.2 on Windows
I'm developing a C++ desktop application on Windows that uses Qt 5.12.12 for its GUI and VTK 8.2 for 3D visualization. I'm searching for a GUI testing tool that can help automate the testing process, specifically targeting:
Qt Widgets: The application includes a variety of standard and custom widgets (buttons, sliders, etc.), and I need a tool that supports testing these components.
VTK Integration: The GUI also displays 3D visualizations using VTK. It would be ideal if the tool supports interactions with VTK render windows.
Signal-Slot Mechanism: The tool should allow testing of Qt’s signal-slot connections to verify the interactive behaviors of the application.
Windows Support: The testing tool must work seamlessly on Windows 11 Pro (64 bit OS), as that is the target platform.
I have explored the following tools but am unsure if they fully meet my requirements:
Squish for Qt: A commercial tool with strong support for Qt, but could not find the correct compatibility with my Qt version.
SikuliX: Works on Windows and is great for visual testing, but it uses image recognition to automate GUI tests.
Google Test (GTest): A widely used C++ testing framework with rich features, such as parameterized tests, mock support, and advanced assertions, but does not support all Qt components like signal and slot mechanisms.
Catch2: A modern, header-only C++ test framework, but this is also similar to google test.
What are the best open-source GUI testing tools for automating tests in a Qt 5.12.12 C++ application with VTK 8.2 on Windows? If you have experience with any of these tools or alternatives, how well do they work for testing both Qt widgets and VTK-based components?
Please put forward your valuable suggestions.

Sorry but asking for personal opinions or recommendations about software/tools/etc. is considered off topic on StackOverflow.

Note that GTest and Catch2 are meant for unit-testing but Squish and SikuliX are meant for automated black-box regression testing. All kinda work, all have limitations (that you can overcome by your scripts and coding), and all will evolve over time. Writing and maintaining tests is work, tools do not test. So all boils down to who likes to work with what. I would perhaps pick Catch2 and SikuliX, but that is as good opinion as any other.
